# Removing input labels from Stripe Payment Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using the Stripe Payment Element in my react app. How can I remove the labels above the inputs:

[image]

Using the appearance API I have tried these rules:

```
'.Label': {
display: 'none',
visibility: 'hidden',
},
'.Label--empty': {
display: 'none',
visibility: 'hidden',
},
```

EDIT:
Found a solution that worked in my case. Using the appearance API you can set Label to 'floating' and the labels will be put inside the inputs:

code:

```
appearance: {
      labels: 'floating',
```

How it looks:

[image]

Comment: if the labels have class including `Label` or `Label-empty` that could would - though, maybe use `!important` - anyway, we can't see the HTML so who knows what class they have. Also, if that form is inside an iframe, then of course you can't

Answer (score 1):

Neither `display` or `visibility` are [supported CSS properties](https://docs.stripe.com/elements/appearance-api?platform=web#supported-css-properties) in the Appearance API.  I have tested a number of options and I don't think you can remove the label text entirely.

The form is rendered inside an iframe so the Appearance API is the only way you have to apply styling to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font-size of the label to 0 if you'd prefer to not show the labels visually and only have the placeholders visible.

```
appearance: {
  rules: {
    '.Label': {
      fontSize: '0'
    }
  }
}
```